# Server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

Tags: certificates

**See edit below**. We are having an issue where we are receiving an error on our Linux server that I am not receiving locally on my mac. on We are using an R library `cfbfastR` to fetch college football sports data. Info on our linux server:

```
root@localhost:/home/joe # uname -a
Linux localhost 4.4.0-193-generic #224-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 6 17:15:28 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

We have the same version of this R library `cfbfastR v.1.3.3`, and although the R code doesn't matter too much, the breaking line is `schedule <- cfbfastR::cfbd_game_info(year = 2021)`. This works locally on mac, but we receive the following error on Linux:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle): server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
Request failed [ERROR]. Retrying in 1 seconds...
```

I checked the file at `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` and:

```
root@localhost:/etc/ssl/certs# cat ca-certificates.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
```

There are somewhere between 100 - 150 different `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` in this file (only 2 shown above). My question is:

- is it normal for there to be 100 - 150 of these in a single `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` file?
- how can we resolve the `Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(...` error?

I have very little linux experience but am tasked with getting this R code to run on this server (I'm an analyst, not a devops / linux expert). Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181231/server-certificate-verification-failed-cafile-etc-ssl-certs-ca-certificates-c

Before I start pasting commands randomly into my console, it does seem like this comment from the thread could be a solution? does this look safe to try?

[image]

Comment: running: `sudo apt update ; sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates -y ; sudo update-ca-certificates` did not resolve our issue :(

Answer (score 3):

From the same thread linked above, this answer worked:

````
In case your system is quite current but for some reason automatic update didn't work, there should be enough to:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

and in reconfigure stage, deselect "DST Root CA X3" certificate.
````

although i did not deselect the "DST Root CA X3" certificate, it still worked and I no longer get the error.